# Avoid XSS in custom Twig function?

Tags: php, function, symfony, twig

What is the riht way to escape XSS in custom Twig function?

Consider this :

```
class TwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'html_helpers';
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        $options = array(
            'is_safe' => array('html')
        );
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('greating', array($this, 'greating'),$options)
        );
    }

    public function greating($name)
    {
        return "Salut ".$name;
    }  
}
```

And the call in the template : `{{ greating("<script>alert('Sébastien')</script>") }}`

It will display the JS alert. How can I avoid this?

Comment: The docs is not enough? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html with the `|e` ?

Comment: @fluminis Pretty new in Twig. Ok, I can do that '{{ greating("<script>alert('Sébastien')</script>")|escape }}', but how can I integrate this in the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prevent scripts like that from getting put in by wrapping the name in `htmlspecialchars` just like the twig escape filter uses internally:

```
public function greating($name)
{
    $escapedName = htmlspecialchars($name);
    return "Salut {$escapedName}";
}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html

> Internally, escape uses the PHP native htmlspecialchars function for the HTML escaping strategy.